Firebase Analytics, Android - new app version is not visible in Analytics Dashboard
We published a new app version - 1.1.0, but in Analytics Dashboard the latest version is still 1.0.2.
At the same time, the version 1.1.0 is available in Crushlytics and Release Monitoring.
What could be the problem?
I've  updated google-service.json - prob isn't solved

I'm having the same issue with an iOS app, find any solution?
